# Netbeans java delete internationalization

Tags: java, netbeans, internationalization

I was trying to work with internationalization of GUI in Netbeans (in Java). I created properties file, I played around with internationalization but I got some strings marked as needed for internationalization wrongly. I got tired of trying to correct my mistake so I just wanted to delete whole internationalization. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do that.

I can't change the auto-generated code where internationalization init happens and I can't find any option to turn it off. Can you help me get rid of it or at least tell me how to mark some strings as not requiring internationalization even though I accidentally internationalized them?

Comment: What's the netbeans version that you work?

Comment: kindly provide all the information in the question...

Answer (score 0):

Select the form from the Navigator and right click on the form and select the properties

[image]

Deselect the Automatic internationalization

[image]

and reload the form again (look at the first pic again)